# Jaxb system path

Tags: jaxb, environment-variables

I just installed java Web Service Developer Pack 2.0 to use JAXB for xml operations. The tutorial says me add "C:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jaxb\bin"  to the system path.I select Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings. I come to the Advanced tab I open the window Environment variables. and i selected PATH from user variables,selected edit and append "C:\Sun\jwsdp-2.0\jaxb\bin" to here. But when i write xjc,it is still not recognized. What should i do more ?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the release notes for JWSDP 2.0, and they're copy right 2005.

- http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/ReleaseNotes.html

If you're just looking to run XJC it is also included as part of Java SE 6.  You can run it as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\xjc
```

As for JAXB implementations you can choose from:

- [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXY)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)
- [Metro JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) (the reference implementation, included in JAVA SE 6.